# Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order on MySQL 8.0.11

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I run Forward Engineer of sakila_full.mwb on MySQL Workbench 6.3.10.
MySQL Server version is 8.0.11.

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `sakila`.`film_text`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sakila`.`film_text` (
      `film_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `description` TEXT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`),
      FULLTEXT INDEX `idx_title_description` (`title` ASC, `description` ASC))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I got following error.

```
ERROR: Error 1221: Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order
```

Why?

**Update1**

I tried a fulltext index is only for TEXT type columns.following this.

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `sakila`.`film_text`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sakila`.`film_text` (
      `film_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `description` TEXT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`),
      FULLTEXT INDEX `idx_title_description` (`description` ASC))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

But i got same error.

```
Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of spatial/fulltext/hash index and explicit index order
```

Comment: You are specifying a VARCHAR and TEXT column in a FULLTEXT index. A fulltext index is only for TEXT type columns.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

That's already been self-settled.
I removed ASC.

```
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table `sakila`.`film_text`
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sakila`.`film_text` (
      `film_id` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      `description` TEXT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`film_id`),
      FULLTEXT INDEX `idx_title_description` (`title`, `description`))
    ENGINE = InnoDB
```

[image: MySQL Workbench]

Thank you.

**Update1**

MySQL Workbench 8.0.11 fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it is superfluously, but that what i found from docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/descending-indexes.html

"Descending indexes are supported for BTREE but not HASH indexes. Descending indexes are not supported for FULLTEXT or SPATIAL indexes.

**Explicitly specified ASC and DESC designators for HASH, FULLTEXT, and SPATIAL indexes results in an error.**"

Comment: The Op says that the have already fixed it by upgrading the workbench !!